# Find and install man file manually

Tags: debian, man, gcc, roff

I seem to be missing some man pages, notably gcc and g++. It doesn't help that I specify the section. `whereis` doesn't list man pages for those two, so I think they are simply not there.

With Google I get a lot, for example: http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++ (seems to be ordinary HTML though... or is it man page markup?)

I thought this would be a good opportunity to learn how to replace them manually. I guess I'm looking for a gcc.1.gz file?

Do I get it from GNU, from Debian, or could it be automated somehow? How much work is put into those files - if I get one, is it likely to be 99% correct or do they really differ a lot with time/architecture?

Comment: For gcc man pages, the package you want is `gcc-doc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the `non-free` and `contrib`  repositories to your sources list and run `apt-get update` afterwards.

Now you can install the `gcc-doc` package which contains the man-pages with:

```
apt-get install gcc-doc
```

The problem is that the gcc documentation is released under the [GNU Free Documentation License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Free_Documentation_License) which is considered [non-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Free_Documentation_License#Criticism) by Debian.

Comment: Yep, that did it. I guess they consider the compilers OK, because I can't recall installing them explicitly from any specific source.

Answer (score 8):

Many GNU projects, including GCC, license their documentation under the [GNU Free Documentation License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Free_Documentation_License). There is a long-standing [dispute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Free_Documentation_License#Criticism) between the Free Software Foundation and the Debian project, which considers the [GFDL to be non-free](http://people.debian.org/~srivasta/Position_Statement.xhtml), mostly because it can forbid some sections of the documentation from being modified.

For this reason, the GCC documentation is not included in the Debian distribution itself. It is, however, distributed by the Debian project as part of the “non-free” repository. That the non-free repository is officially supported by Debian but not officially part of Debian is the result of much debate and compromise inside the Debian project.

You can search on the [Debian website](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) for a package containing the file `g++.1` (select “packages that contain files whose names contain the keyword”, because the man page is actually compressed so the file name is `g++.1.gz`). You'll find it in the [gcc-VERSION-doc](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gcc-doc) package, which is a meta-package in the contrib repository that depends on the gcc-VERSION-doc package in the non-free repository.

On your machine, make sure that you have the contrib and non-free repositories enabled. Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should contain a line like

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian squeeze main non-free contrib
```

or multiple lines like

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian squeeze contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian squeeze non-free
```

If you modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`, run `apt-get update` as root afterwards. Once you have these repositories in your sources, you can use [apt-file](http://packages.debian.org/apt-file) to search for the package containing a file by name. You need to run `apt-file update` as root after installing the program or modifying the sources list.

```
apt-file search g++.1
```

Once you find what package the file you want is in (as indicated above, you want the `g++-doc` package), use `apt-get install g++-doc` or whatever your favorite package manager is.

Comment: Wow, apt-file is indeed very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install manpages for development, as:

```
$ apt-get install manpages-dev
```